# Interface Builder: How to select nested elements?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder, ios

Is there a way in interface builder to maybe see a tree of my elements so that I could select them that way. It's very hard to select things inside the actual view itself, especially when I have alot of elements and nested views, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try holding shift and right clicking on an element. It should show you a menu of the view hierarchy under that element.

Actually, wait, that shows you elements *above* this one in the heirarchy. What you want to do is use the Nib window (not the view of the Nib, but the other one with File's Owner and such), choose 'Window' and then set it column view, this way you can navigate around easier.

Comment: sweet, that's exactly what i was looking for